# Random graph generator

Tags: igraph, networkx

I am interested in generating weighted, directed random graphs with node constraints. Is there a graph generator in R or Python that is customizable? The only one I am aware of is igraph's `erdos.renyi.game()` but I am unsure if one can customize it.

Edit: the customizations I want to make are 1) drawing a weighted graph and 2) constraining some nodes from drawing edges.

Comment: Yes.  For example, networkx has some.  There are probably an infinite number of different ways one might want to "customize" a random graph generator.  Whether these can be customized to what you want is therefore hard to say.

Comment: Thanks. Clarified what I meant by customization.

Answer (score 1):

In igraph python, you can use [link](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html)  the **Erdos_Renyi** class.

For constraining some nodes from drawing edges, this is controlled by the p value.

```
Erdos_Renyi(n, p, m, directed=False, loops=False) #these are the defaults
```

Example:

```
from igraph import *

g = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(10,0.1,directed=True)
plot(g)
```

By setting the p=0.1 you can see that some nodes do not have edges.

For the weights you can do something like:

```
g.ecount() # to find the number of edges
g.es["weights"] = range(1, g.ecount())
g.es["label"] = weights
plot(g)
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Constraints mean certain nodes have p=0 while unconstrained nodes have p>0

Comment: Oh. okay I will try to find a way and modify my answer. nodes with p=0 means no edges in your case right?

Comment: Nodes with p=0 cannot form edges, but they can receive edges. Nodes with p>0 can form and receive edges.

Comment: Also, you are adding weights after generating the graph instead of generating a weighted graph.

Comment: Yes. In the erdos renyi case you need to add the weights after the creation of the graph. Also you can use random module in order to produce random weights. As for the edge formation this type of customization need other module like networkx